# Button group bootstrap

Tags: class

.btn-group placing.

when using button group for coding in Bootstrap do you place this .btn-group into a div or class. When placing this in a code does it always stay in the one or can this be placed in multiple while coding? For reference, if needed, I use Replit for coding this.